# Is server-side Vue.js with ES6 possible on a Java server?

Tags: javascript, java, vue.js, ecmascript-6, rhino

With vue-server-renderer 2.5 [being platform agnostic](https://gist.github.com/yyx990803/9bdff05e5468a60ced06c29c39114c6b#environment-agnostic-ssr), I can't help but want to render some of my Vue.js components on the server for general betterness.

The doc mentions Nashorn, which doesn't seem to appear on many compatability tables. I know our server currently has [Rhino 1.7.7](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/). I also notice that on the kangax compatability table, Rhino is listed as 'obsolete'. The Vue.js docs mention Nashorn (JJS on the compat table) which does better than Rhino, but still missing key ES6 features.

It seems to me like if we are developing Vue components using ES6, then we'd have to compile them using babel in our node environments and include them somehow on the server? Otherwise we'd have to throw away most ES6 syntax across the board since we'd be looking at reusing components.

I'm trying to assess the difficulty/value of whether it's worth going down this path and if there are other tools or approaches that would help us get closer.

Comment: Use a Node server?

Comment: Don't use Rhino, nobody does it. You will face a ton of problems and you will be alone in the world. I feel you, many times I've wanted to move forward while keeping the current infrastructure because reason, but that's just not worthwile. Just imagine getting random errors, pasting on google and finding only foruns of 2013 and below, if ever.

Comment: @acdcjunior oh yeah. i get that.. as a front end dev in a large enterprise i can't really replace our infrastructure but i can potentially ask for new packages to be installed

Comment: You may try Graalvm. It supports es7